# Count all true on right cell where cells = "Raid"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

After some research, I did not find what I want, that is to say to count the number of item coming from "Raid" not checked, I thus come to ask for your help!

Currently I have a google sheet that lists the achievement of each player in the group on items.

To do this I have created a table with the name of the source of the item in column B and the obtainment with a checkbox in column C.
Here is the example:
[Google sheet exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxC1H.png)

I have already tried this function
`=ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1, 4)` and `INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)`
but it gives me an error "Formula parse error".

If you have an idea, I'm interested, thanks in advance! :D

Edit : Here an exemple of what i want to have in the end : [Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkWZF.png)

An automated fonction to count every "false" checkbox where it's "Raid" on left cells.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what the output should be. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Alfredo Edited with a screenshot of what i want in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) is helpful for this kind of situations. Assuming that you only have 5 rows of data, you can use the next formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(B1:B5, "Raid", C1:C5, FALSE)
```

Comment: Ty so much, works great!